# How can I create a state store that is restorable from an existing changelog topic?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am using the streams DSL to deduplicate a topic called `users`:

```
topology.addStateStore(Stores.keyValueStoreBuilder(Stores.persistentKeyValueStore("users"), byteStringSerde, userSerde));                                                                                                                                                   

KStream<ByteString, User> users = topology.stream("users", Consumed.with(byteStringSerde, userSerde));                                                                                                                                                                      

users.transform(() -> new Transformer<ByteString, User, KeyValue<ByteString, User>>() {                                                                                                                                                                                     

    private KeyValueStore<ByteString, User> store;                                                                                                                                                                                                                          

    @Override                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    public void init(ProcessorContext context) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
        store = (KeyValueStore<ByteString, User>) context.getStateStore("users");                                                                                                                                                                                           
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       

    @Override                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    public KeyValue<ByteString, User> transform(ByteString key, User value) {                                                                                                                                                                                               
        User user = store.get(key);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
        if (user != null) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
            store.put(key, value);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
            return new KeyValue<>(key, value);                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
        }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
        return null;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       

    @Override                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    public KeyValue<ByteString, User> punctuate(long timestamp) {                                                                                                                                                                                                           
        return null;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       

    @Override                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    public void close() {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   

    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
}, "users");
```

Given this code, Kafka Streams creates an internal changelog topic for the `users` store. I am wondering, **is there some way I can use the existing `users` topic instead of creating an essentially identical changelog topic?**

PS. I see that [`StreamsBuilder`](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/4d544d4f08b027ce318b088b112f03dccc566098/streams/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/StreamsBuilder.java#L193) says this is possible:

> However, no internal changelog topic is created since the original input topic can be used for recovery

But following the code to `InternalStreamsBuilder#table()` and `InternalStreamsBuilder#createKTable()`, I am not seeing how it's achieving this effect.

Comment: Having thought through this problem for a while, I understand how the original `users` topic and the `users` store changelog topic are semantically/conceptually different. So maybe that's the crux of the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all thing the DSL does are possible at the Processor API level -- it's using some internals, that are not part of public API to achieve what you describe.

It's the call to `InternalTopologyBuilder#connectSourceStoreAndTopic()` that does the trick (cf. `InternalStreamsBuilder#table()`).

For your use case about de-duplication, it seem that you need two topics though (depending what de-duplication logic you apply). Restoring via a changelog topic does key-based updates and thus does not consider values (that might be part of your deduplication logic, too).

Comment: I am not above using internal APIs though, provided I understand them well. Just seems kind of strange that I need to duplicate a stream just to join it against itself. `connectSourceAndTopic()` is one of the few routes I did not explore in that code path. Maybe I'll take a look :)

Comment: Looking at `connectSourceAndTopic()`—appears that it just adds the topic to the `storeToChangelogTopic` map, which KafkaStreams must use restore on start if it deems necessary. Good to know. Thank you.